# Create objects without causing a stack overflow error?

Tags: java, object, stack-overflow

So, I have my main class that calls `private Secondary secondary = new Secondary();` when it runs. In the Secondary class, at the top I have code that says `private Main main = new Main();`.

How will I be able to use all of the methods and variables from the Secondary class and vice versa without causing a stack overflow error?

Note: they are not in the constructor

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense:  stack overflow errors are caused by calling too many nested methods, not by creating objects.

Comment: @Wyzard: It makes perfect sense - initializing a `Secondary` requires initializing a new `Main`, which requires initializing a new `Secondary` etc. It's recursive construction, rather than recursive method calls.

Comment: @JonSkeet, only if the calls are in the constructor, which the question doesn't specify, though it seems like a plausible interpretation.  I'd assumed that the first sentence was referring to code in a *static* `main()` method.

Comment: @Wyzard: Those are clearly *field* declarations (otherwise `private` would be invalid), with variable initializers.

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Main class is creating a Secondary instance, which is creating a Main instance..., and this is causing the stack overflow error.

I think you just want the objects to refer to each other, so don't create the other class's new instance in the constructor.  Declare references as instance variables, and use setter methods to store existing references to objects of the other type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to handle safe (non-recursive) initialization of your instance fields (via setters).